# psycopg2 can't find my python26 installation

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I believe it's because I installed python using SciPy, so apparently it's not in the registry where the psycopg2 installer is looking. Anyway to fix this without installing python26 over the existing install? I'm not sure if that will corrupt it.

EDIT: My PYTHONPATH looks like the following:

```
'C:\\Python26\\scripts',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\apptools-3.3.0-py2.6.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\blockcanvas-3.1.0-py2.6-win32.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\chaco-3.2.0-py2.6-win32.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\codetools-3.1.0-py2.6.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\configobj-4.6.0-py2.6.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\enable-3.2.0-py2.6-win32.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\enthoughtbase-3.0.3-py2.6.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\envisagecore-3.1.1-py2.6.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\envisageplugins-3.1.1-py2.6.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\ets-3.3.0-py2.6.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\etsdevtools-3.0.3-py2.6-win32.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\etsprojecttools-0.5.1-py2.6.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\mayavi-3.3.0-py2.6-win32.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\scimath-3.0.4-py2.6-win32.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\setupdocs-1.0.3-py2.6.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\traits-3.2.0-py2.6-win32.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\traitsbackendqt-3.2.0-py2.6.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\traitsbackendwx-3.2.0-py2.6.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\traitsgui-3.1.0-py2.6.egg',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\python_twitter-0.6-py2.6.egg',
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenLibraries\\python',
'C:\\Python26\\python26.zip',
'C:\\Python26\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python26\\lib',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\plat-win',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\lib-tk',
'C:\\Python26',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
'c:\\python26\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode',
'C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython/Extensions',
```

Comment: What does your PYTHONPATH environment variable look like? Regardless of your operating system if you `import sys` and examine `sys.path` you should get your answer.

Comment: See above edit. Also looks like there's no entry in the registry, which I think setuptools based python installers look for.

Answer (score 1):

I found this script which can fix it:

http://effbot.org/zone/python-register.htm